# How to check Elastic Beanstalk environment variable in Bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to access an Elastic Beanstalk environment variable from a bash script (within `.platform/hooks/postdeploy/`.

The script is something like:

```
if [[ -v "${WORKER_ENV}" ]]; then
    echo -e "Happy times - worker env\n"
    # Do stuff I want to do
else
    echo -e "No worker env variable"
fi
```

I have 2 instances of the same application.  In 1, I have specified `WORKER_ENV` in the `Configuration > Environment properties`.  In the other I haven't.

When I deploy the application in both environments, the log file shows "No worker env variable".  How do I get the script to pick up an environment variable from the `Configuration > Environment properties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this, I solved as follows:

```
WORKER = 0
SUBSTRING="WORKER_ENV"
while read line; do  
    if [[ "$line" == *"$SUBSTRING"* ]]; then
        WORKER=1
        echo "Found WORKER_ENV"
    fi
done < /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/custom_env_var

if [[ $WORKER == 1 ]]; then
    echo -e "Happy times - worker env\n"
```

In another script I had already copied the `env` file to `custom_env_var` because I previously had trouble accessing the `env` file once the application was deployed in cron jobs.  This is working fine now